# How to convert a downloaded string to datetime format?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to check if **today's date < date downloaded from text file online**. Here is my code :

```
import datetime
import requests

URL = "http://directlinktotextfile.com/text.txt"
result = requests.get(URL)

today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
Url_date = result.text
Url_date.strip()
Url_date = datetime.date(Url_date)



if today < Url_date :
    print "Today is less than future date"
    raw_input()
else:
    print "Today is greater than or = to future date"
    raw_input()
```

The result that comes back is just this : **2018,02,14**. I use .strip() in case there might be blank spaces or extra lines. I've printed out result.text after strip() and it shows the correct details. Why is it that I can't check if **today < Url_date**. It works fine if I enter manually a date into **datetime.date(2018,02,14)**, but when I'm downloading the string it won't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass string to `datetime.date()` which should be each an integer.

```
Url_list = []
Url_list = Url_date.split(",")
yr = int(Url_list[0])
mn = int(Url_list[1])
d = int(Url_list[2])
```

Now pass these integers to `datetime.date`

```
Url_date = datetime.date(yr, mn, d)
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood this one more. I updated everyone though for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

The arguments you pass to `datetime.date(arg1, arg2, arg3)` are not strings as a whole. When you pass it from url, what you are actually doing is

```
datetime.date("2018,2,14")
```

Note that you are passing only one string argument and not 3 different integers. You should split the date string using comma and then convert each into integers and then pass them as arguments to datetime.date.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your code is trying to do :

```
Url_date = datetime.date("2018,02,14")
```

But he wants to have:

```
Url_date = datetime.date(2018,02,14)
```

Do

```
Url_date.split(',') # Result: ['2018','02','14']
```

And then convert all the `string` in the `array` in `integers`

It should be ok  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
parsed = datetime.datetime.strptime("2018,02,14", "%Y,%m,%d").date()
print(today < parsed) # True
```

Comment: "2018,02,14". I need to pass that value from the result downloaded online. If it was a manual input it was no problem

Comment: I didn't down vote so I don't know. I up voted for the help